# Unity2D - Placing text HP and health bar over character sprite

Tags: unity, 2d

I've got a 2D character sprite that I will move through a game board. I want to add over it, in a corner of the sprite, a Text object with the remaining HP of that character and also a health bar. I want those elements to move with the Character. Wherever the character moves, the UI follows.

I've tried adding a Text element in World Space and attaching it to the character sprite, but the Text is so huge that it's not displayed properly on top of it. I need to know how to adapt that text to the size of the sprite and how to make it follow it automatically. I guess that by setting the ch sprite as parent of the Text/canvas it would work, but I don't know how to get it working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
public Vector2 WorldToCanvasPoint(Vector3 a_position)
{
    Vector2 viewport = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(a_position);
    return Vector2.right * (viewport.x - 0.5f) * m_canvasRect.width + Vector2.up * (viewport.y-0.5f) * m_canvasRect.height;
}
```

This is what you are looking for. 
Put this code on your Canvas, it could be called "CanvasManager" and should be a singleton. You can get m_canvasRect by doing:

```
this.GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
```

Then you can create a "FollowTransform" script, with a

```
public Transform m_objectToFollow;
```

variable on it.

You put this script "FollowTransform" script on your HP Text, and add this:

```
public Transform m_objectToFollow;
private RectTransform m_rect;

void Start()
{
    m_rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

void Update()
{
    this.m_rect.anchoredPosition = CanvasManager.Instance.WorldToCanvasPoint(m_objectToFollow.position);
}
```

This way, the text will follow the transform you specified.

If you don't know how to create a singleton and what is it, you should search on google "Singleton design pattern". It's really useful and commonly used.
Here's a way of doing it:

```
public class CanvasManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static CanvasManager _instance;
    public static CanvasManager Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    void Start () {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Manual on [World Space UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)

For a health bar, the Slider component would be ideal. Your HealthBar component script would require a Slider, and Health component, make the canvas follow the transform, and set its value to the health of the object.